# Trouble with CSS no loading in PHP with XAMPP

Tags: html

I am creating a website using PHP with XAMPP. The issue that I have is that my CSS is not loading. I have tried adding the extension of .php to my CSS file. I also changed my HTML file to PHP and still nothing.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Home page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

  </head>

  <body>

    <header>

      <img src="logo/logo.jpg" alt="" />

      <nav>

        <ul>

          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

          <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>

          <li><a href="sign.html">Sign Up</a></li>

          <li><a href="info.html">Information</a></li>

        </ul>

      </nav>

      <div class="container">

        <div class="line1"></div>

        <div class="line2"></div>

        <div class="line3"></div>

      </div>

      <form action="">

        <input type="text" />

      </form>

      <button>submit</button>

    </header>

    <section></section>

    <main>

      <p></p>

    </main>

    <footer></footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
/*

html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet

v1.6.1

Last Updated: 2010-09-17

Author: Richard Clark - http://richclarkdesign.com

Twitter: @rich_clark

*/


html, body, div, span, object, iframe,

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,

abbr, address, cite, code,

del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,

small, strong, sub, sup, var,

b, i,

dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,

fieldset, form, label, legend,

table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,

article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,

footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,

time, mark, audio, video {

    margin:0;

    padding:0;

    border:0;

    outline:0;

    font-size:100%;

    vertical-align:baseline;

    background:transparent;

}


body {

    line-height:1;

}


article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,

footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {

    display:block;

}


nav ul {

    list-style:none;

}


blockquote, q {

    quotes:none;

}


blockquote:before, blockquote:after,

q:before, q:after {

    content:'';

    content:none;

}


a {

    margin:0;

    padding:0;

    font-size:100%;

    vertical-align:baseline;

    background:transparent;

}


/* change colours to suit your needs */

ins {

    background-color:#ff9;

    color:#000;

    text-decoration:none;

}


/* change colours to suit your needs */

mark {

    background-color:#ff9;

    color:#000;

    font-style:italic;

    font-weight:bold;

}


del {

    text-decoration: line-through;

}


abbr[title], dfn[title] {

    border-bottom:1px dotted;

    cursor:help;

}


table {

    border-collapse:collapse;

    border-spacing:0;

}


/* change border colour to suit your needs */

hr {

    display:block;

    height:1px;

    border:0;  

    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;

    margin:1em 0;

    padding:0;

}


input, select {

    vertical-align:middle;

}


/*My code*/


* {

  box-sizing: border-box;

}


header{

  width: 100%;

  background-color: #3F6384;

}


header img {

  width: 100px;

  height: 100px;

}


header nav {

  position: absolute;

  right: 0;

  top: 140px;

}
```

Comment: Is something wrong with the path `css/style.css` ? What do you actually mean by saying `my css is not loading`

Comment: I checked and no there is no issues

Comment: _..I checked and no there is no issues..._ How did you check?

Comment: I tried it as an html file outside the htdocs. I opened the html file but when I open it in localhost no style appears.

Comment: Run the code in your browser, then take a look at the source code(within your browser) click the css, if it doesn't load, the path is broken

Comment: This question should not be tagged `php`. Please edit your post and tag it with `html` and `css`.

Answer (score 0):

Your url in the CSS import link indicates that you have a structur like this, is that correct?

```
htdocs/
    index.php
    css/
        style.css
```

If your index.php or what ever name it has is in another folder, try changing to this, since without the leading '/' it's a relative directory from the page you're currently at. With the slash it's relative to the root directory.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Try entering this in your webbrowser. (localhost might be diffrent depending on your setup) http://localhost/css/style.css
Do you see the css file in your browser then?

Comment: It gives me object not found the requested url  was not found on this server. If you enterd the url manually please check your spelling and try again. If you think this is a sever error, please contact webmaster. Error 404 localhost apache/2.4.41(win64) openssl/1.1.1c php/7.311

Comment: Then there is XAMPP can find you css file. Are you sure it's place in e.g. "C:/<username>/xampp/htdocs/css/style.css/".

If you have a project folder like this:
"C:/<username>/xampp/htdocs/Project1/css/style.css/", you need to change you'r **href** tag when loading the css file, to: <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Project1/css/style.css" />

Comment: Yes I checked I have it in htdocs projects css (folder) style.css